# Is it possible to use Invoke Webrequest to login to a site that is using Azure AD B2C authentication?

Tags: powershell, authentication, azure-ad-b2c, invoke-webrequest

I am trying to configure my build-server to warmup my website by using a PowerShell script, that visits the website and login. The entire website is behind login.

My website is using Azure AD B2C for authentication and has been configured using the starter guide from Microsoft: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

When I login through the browser everything works as expected.

My current code for login looks like this:

```
$session = Get-AuthenticatedSession $DomainName $config.authenticationDetails $UserName $Password

Function Get-AuthenticatedSession {
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [string]$domainName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [object]$authenticationDetails,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=2)]
    [string]$username,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=3)]
    [string]$password
  )

  # Login - to create web session with authorisation cookies
  $loginPage = "$domainName$($authenticationDetails.url)"

  Write-Host "Getting Login Page $loginPage"

  try{
    $login = Invoke-WebRequest $loginPage -SessionVariable webSession -TimeoutSec 600 -UseBasicParsing
  }catch{
    Write-Host "First attempt failed with $($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__) , retrying"
    $login = Invoke-WebRequest $loginPage -SessionVariable webSession -TimeoutSec 600 -UseBasicParsing
  }

  Write-Host "Got Login Page, filling out form"

  $fields = @{}
  $fields["$($authenticationDetails.userNameField)"] = $username
  $fields["$($authenticationDetails.passwordField)"] = $password

  Write-Host "logging in"

  $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $loginPage -WebSession $webSession -Method POST -Body $form  -TimeoutSec 600| Out-Null

  $webSession

  Write-Host "login done"
}
```

This is my code for requesting a page behind login, which is run afterwards:

```
foreach ($page in $config.urls) {
    RequestPage "$DomainName$($page.url)" $session
}

Function RequestPage {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
        [string]$url,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
        [object]$webSession
    )
    Get-Date
    Write-Host "requesting $url ..."
    try { $request = Invoke-WebRequest $url -WebSession $webSession -TimeoutSec 60000 -UseBasicParsing} catch {
      $status = $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.Value__
      if ($status -ne 200){
        Write-Host "ERROR Something went wrong while requesting $url" -foregroundcolor red
      }
    }

    Write-Host $request

    Get-Date
    Write-Host "Done"
    Write-Host ""
}
```

The problem is that the script does not seem to login correctly. Whenever I request a page behind login, I always get the html of the login page back. Any help is much appreciated!

*EDIT* - It seems like there is no FORM element on the page - doh! The actual signin is a button-element with a javascript click event attached. The login page is hosted by Microsoft, so I have little control over the DOM elements:

```
<div class="buttons">
            <button id="next" tabindex="1">Sign in</button>
          </div>
```

So I guess my question is whether it is possible to trigger a button click using PowerShell? When I also want the script to run on my build server where IE might not be available

Answer (score 1):

I've not had a reason to mess with Azure AD B2C, so, no experience as to what that site is or what you can do on it. However, as for ...

> So I guess my question is whether it is possible to trigger a button
>   click using PowerShell? When I also want the script to run on my build
>   server where IE might not be available

...  the simple answer is, yes, as discussed and demoed in the article... [Teaching PowerShell to Click](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/teaching-powershell-click). Red the article for full explanation

In a PowerShell Editor - In this case I'm using the ISE - of course in VSCode as well.

```
# View the page live to se what it does - just do stuff
Start-Process 'http://www.minasi.com/addit.htm'

# Now, inspect the site page/form. 
# View the page code to see what is there - If in the ISE

$minasi = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.minasi.com/addit.htm'
$minasi.Content | Out-ISETab
$minasi.AllElements | Out-ISETab
$minasi.Forms | Out-ISETab
$minasi.Forms.Fields | Out-ISETab
$minasi.InputFields | Out-ISETab

# View the page code to see what is there - If in VSCode

$minasi = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.minasi.com/addit.htm'
$minasi.Content | New-EditorFile
$minasi.AllElements | New-EditorFile
$minasi.Forms | New-EditorFile
$minasi.Forms.Fields | New-EditorFile
$minasi.InputFields | New-EditorFile


# Interact with the page to achieve the same results as GUI would by going direct to the 'results page' not the 'form page'.

$MethodPostURI = 'http://www.minasi.com/addit-worker.asp'
$Body ='addend1=3&addend2=9&B1=SUBMIT%21'
$page = Invoke-WebRequest $MethodPostURI -body $Body -method POST
$page.content


# You can also find elements by looping to find something specific, like the below...
$minasi.AllElements.FindById('SomeIdNameString')

# Or 

$SubmitElement = $minasi.AllElements | 
Where{
        $PSItem.tagName -eq 'INPUT' -and 
        $PSItem.value -eq 'SUBMIT!'
     }
$SubmitElement # The use dot lookup to see if there is a click option.
```

Lastly, here is something you may want to take a look at.

> [pQuery](https://github.com/misterGF/pQuery)
>
> This module is meant to create a variable that we can use jQuery-like
>   syntax to do jQuery-like manipulations on a website.